# Change global language in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I want to change the main language just for my app (not the whole phone). When the user selects **spanish** in the settings menu the whole app should from now be in spanish. I searched a lot and found everytime that the solution is to override the **AppleLanguages** key in **NSUserDefaults**. So I made this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"es", @"de", @"en", @"ru", @"it", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When I restart the app I do a log in the **AppDelegate** and the **AppleLanguages** is set to the default order (Spanish not the first language what it should be) and the global app language is set to default. Is this the right way?

Comment: Are you testing/debugging localization? If so, you want to [make this a launch argument](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/07/22/using-launch-arguments-to-test-localizations.html).

Comment: No, I'am not switching the language in the simulator :) I want to switch the language inside my app. Inside my app the user hast the possibility to change the whole language of the app.